# Magento pricing attribute not working

Tags: attributes, price, url

I am having difficulty setting magento price filter.

It seem to be showing the wrong url when selecting any price range

Wrong url: https://www.mysite.co.uk/pc-components/components?price%5B0%5D=0&price%5B1%5D=25

But when I change the url to https://www.mysite.co.uk/pc-components/components?price=0-25

It works fine

I have gone through all the settings and nothing seem to be wrong with it.

Can some one tell me how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

It appears the url is being encoded when it is passed to the GET request. I'm thinking that's probably what is throwing it off. Can you try a [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) on the parameter before you pass it into the logic to set the price range?

EDIT: As I look at the source I posted, I now see GET variables are decoded by default, so instead of looking to add a decode, you should check to see if the logic to pass the values into the url does some sort of encoding before passing it in. Any luck yet?

Comment: Hi why is coding on very first place? We havnt made any changes to our magento and it is a fresh installation of magento as well. We are using stock in the channel plugin. Can that interfere with urls?

Comment: No luck with this code so far. Our site is computersdeal.co.uk for your reference

Comment: Was this working before and suddenly stopped or has this never worked in the first place? I am looking into the plugin you mentioned now.

Comment: I can see your list items are pointing at the incorrect url via onclick="setLocation('http://www.computersdeal.co.uk/pc-components?price%5B0%5D=0&price%5B1%5D=25')" I'd need to see the code that builds these list items to figure out why it is building out the setLocation url incorrectly. I would start there and try to figure out how it sets those links.

Comment: Hi Joshua, no we just installed the magento few days ago I just noticed that the price filter is not working. When you are saying list item pointing to wrong url what you mean by that? I can see everything is going on site computersdeal.co.uk

Comment: OK so the module that handles the price break stuff creates an unordered list of list items that, when clicked, go to a specific link. Right now, the links that they go to look like yoursite.co.uk/pc-components?price%5B0%5D=0&price%5B1%5D=25%27 when they should look like yoursite.co.uk/pc-components/components?price=0-25. That means that the logic that puts those links together is making them incorrectly. At this point, I can't help without looking at the code itself. I would speak with your developer and ask him to look into the logic that builds those links.